# What is $c$ in Gaussian Units?

Tags: speed-of-light, units

Is the speed of light in Gaussian Units just 1 or can it be expressed in metric units?

I am getting really confused by all the unit systems. In relativity, for instance, c is often set equal to 1 and in quantum field theory $\hbar$ is also often set equal to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speed of light in what you would normally call Gaussian units is precisely 29,979,245,800 cm/s.

“Setting $c=1$” is a convenient shorthand in several unit systems including Planck units, to try to normalize the units of energy and mass (say) with a sort of informal symbolic confusion that is usually not too complicated to undo.

At some point I was trying to come up with [a semiserious proposal](https://github.com/crdrost/essay-seeds/blob/master/misc/rational_units.md) for “rational units” based on the idea that “nobody uses the SI unit of the kilosecond so therefore something has gone terribly wrong.” The speed of light in those units was $10^9$ gigadees per instant, where an instant is roughly a microday and this unit defines the dee as a length approximately comparable to an Imperial inch. (It's almost exactly 2% longer, to be more precise.)

I was also able  to fix the unit of charge, one lor, as $-10^{15}$ elementary charges and thus a lor per instant is a little under two milliamps, with electrons having “positive” charge. There is a slight cost to this in that if you want to use Gaussian or Lorentz-Heaviside conventions you have to essentially fix the force unit to be a relatively small one, 1 newt = 4.32 millinewtons. The natural unit for mass is therefore about one gram. But if you do this you can do a Gaussian-style unit pun to create the Maxwell equations in the form nobody uses, $$\begin{align}
\nabla \cdot E &= c \rho & \nabla \times E &= -c^{-1} \frac{\partial B}{\partial t} \\
\nabla \cdot B &= 0 & \nabla \times B &= J + c^{-1} \frac{\partial E}{\partial t}
\end{align}$$
and the reason for choosing this particuar form is that this resulting 4.32 millinewtons of force leads to a typical unit of electric potential which is very reasonable, the newt-dee-per-lor is about 0.7 volts. Like the equations above are exact per definition, but pursuing this dogmatically leads to the strange derivations for the unit of mass and the force constant.

My point taking you through all of that is just to point out that searching for purity in these equations, like Gaussian units do, can actually make it *harder* to fix various constants $=1$ in all of our equations.

Comment: So once we chose Gaussian units, we cannot set c=1 anymore, right?

Comment: @xabdax Well, that's a tricky question to answer. You cannot set $c=1$ in the normal set of Gaussian CGS units, because you are forced to use seconds and centimeters there and $c$ is not one centimeter per second. But you _can_ use unit systems which do what Gaussian units do with the Maxwell equations, and thereby fix $c$. For example Planck units do this, they are “Gaussian” in the sense that $\nabla\cdot E = 4\pi\rho$ but they are not based on centimeters or seconds.

Comment: Observational X-ray astronomers measure exposure times in kiloseconds!

Comment: That is fair! I just mean that given the role of time in society, and the professed value of the metric system, one would expect more. Students know speeds in m/s and km/hr and every once in awhile a bright student works out that the relationship between them has to do with this number 3.6, but the fact that they have to go non-metric at all is really surprising—yet so human. “If I drive at the speed for an hour how far do I go?” But if your fundamental timekeeping unit is 86.4 seconds, roughly a minute and a half, then you never have any speed scales not covered by the unit system.

Answer (score 3):

In Gaussian units the units for length, mass, and time are the centimeter, the gram, and the second (CGS). So the value of $c$ is 29,979,245,800 cm/s (about $3\times 10^{10}$ cm/s).

What makes Gaussian units nice is that Coulomb’s Law has no pointless factor of $\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}$, the Biot-Savart Law doesn’t have an equally pointless $\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}$, and electric and magnetic fields have the same units. Engineers have somehow managed to foist SI hell on current physics textbooks. Even Jackson’s *Classical Electrodynamics* has surrendered in its Third Edition, at least for the first ten chapters.